# Having trouble with Munkres Topology theorem 19.5

Tags: general-topology

> Theorem 19.5 in Munkres Let {$X_α$} be an indexed family of spaces; let $A_α⊂X_α$ for each α. If $∏Xα$ is given either the product or the box topology, then
> $∏Ā_α$ = $\overline{∏Aα}$

Proof. Let $x=(x_α)$ be a point of $∏Ā_α$
; we show that x∈
$\overline{∏Aα}$
. Let $U=∏U_α$ be a basis element for either the box or product topology that contains x. Since $x_\alpha$ $\in$ $\bar{A}_{\alpha}$, we can choose a point $y_\alpha$ $\in U_\alpha$ $\cap A_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$. Then $y=(y_\alpha)$ belongs to both U and . Since U is arbitrary, it follows that x belongs to the closure of $\prod A_{\alpha}$

And I don't quite follow the proof is there any other way to prove this?

I don't understand the part where he says U is arbitrary so it follows that x belongs to the  closure of $\prod A_\alpha$ and also if there is any correlation between x and y and what do they mean by x = $(x_\alpha)$ if they mean the set of all $x_\alpha$?
Also any help with the latex would be appreciated
Aditya

Comment: By $(x_\alpha)$ he means a specific arbitrary point of the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Munkres has earlier in the book proved a lemma:

> Let $X$ be a topological space with base $\mathcal{B}$ and $A \subseteq X$. Then $x \in \overline{A}$ iff for every basic set $B \in \mathcal B$ with $x \in B$ we have $B \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

This is in fact one of the main "applications" of bases for a topology.

He applies this to $A=\prod_\alpha A_\alpha \subseteq \prod_\alpha X_\alpha$ and the two standard bases: all sets of the form $\prod_\alpha U_\alpha$ where we just know that all $U_\alpha$ are open in $X_\alpha$ for the box topology and where for the product topology we have a finite subset $F$ of the index set $A$ so that $\alpha \notin F$ implies $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$. We don't even use that $F$ here, just that a product open base set is also a box base set.